# Can't get followers to touch the altar in Boethiah's Calling

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I listened to people when they said that mercenaries work the best for the altar. When I ask them to do something, I point it at the altar and press my action button(B). The menu would then disappear and nothing would happen. This has happened many times before.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I remember I had a problem with this also. I think you don't command the follower to touch the alter but you have to? It was something weird like that. But I'll try to look into it for you and  help you.

Comment: I have also experienced this glitch, though on the PC version of the game. Console commands were the only fix I was able to find.

Answer (score 3):

Doing some research and replaying the mission on a random character I had found out a way to do it. Following this video so if it worked I could link you it.

[The video is a step by step guide on the best way to doing the quest while explaining and showing what he is doing. Now this is on Xbox but it shouldn't matter.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cI5E1imqQqI)

If this doesn't work it could be a glitch so I advise going back to a previous save and doing the quest again with a different follower.